# Changes in array does not save and does not render on the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, database, next.js, axios

Im getting array from database which contains data which displays on a page, im making some changes to that data save them but they doesnot get rendered on the page
useState doesnot save my changes and they are not getting displayed

```
const [boardSection, setBoardSections] = useState(Leads)
```

```
return (
   boardSection.map((item)) => (
      <div>
          {item.title}
      </div>
   )
)
```

```
<button onClick={() => {
   axios.post(`/api/leads/${active.id}`, {
      stage: overContainer,
    }).then(() => {
      router.refresh();
    })
}}>Refresh</button>
```

I want to it display all the changes instantly on the page, without refreshing the page first

Comment: Have you tried calling setBoardSections after making the API call? Make sure the API returns the updated data though